# Is chat gone from the title bar permanently?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign

I was looking for a private room on Ask Different chat - and saw the link I usually follow at the top gone.

It's still in the link roll at the bottom, but I kind of liked it at the top.

Is this a temporary removal or something more permanent?

[image]

Comment: In addition, why do we have a link to the SE blog? Surely that's more appropriate for the bottom (not site-specific) than this site's chat room.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101464/eeeek-where-did-the-chat-top-navigation-link-go

Comment: I'd put the SE info on the far left where the combined "hot questions" live - not amongst the Ask Different specific search, faq, meta/main [chat] and review links live

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kyle pointed that this might be a temporary thing.

[Eeeek! Where did the chat top navigation link go?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101464/eeeek-where-did-the-chat-top-navigation-link-go)

It appears when the Stack Exchange blog is updated - it pre-empts the normal chat link for Ask Different. I would expect (and appreciate) to see the "new blog" bubble and link to the immediate right of the Stack**Exchange** pull down rather than embedded between the Ask Different specific review, chat, meta and faq links.

[image]

Stack Exchange general information on the far left.
Ask Different specific links on the right.

Comment: this has since been changed; only sites with a per-site blog will get the top notification, e.g. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/

Comment: Thanks Jeff! I liked seeing it and would have never seen the blog otherwise - perhaps it can come back to the right of "Stack Exchange" on the far, far left. Add in the blog, but leaving the right past my name or the "login" link for Ask Different only links.

Comment: metas are still hooked up to the SE/SO blog so just visit your meta to see the [new] blog indicator in that case.

Comment: +1 I like the idea of the StackExchange blog notice on the left where the StackExchange drop down is.

Answer (score 1):

"new" is gone on the main AD site (but not on this meta AD site, oddly), but "blog" still remains instead of chat, so it looks like this is a permanent change, unfortunately. I hope they change it back - I used the chat link at the top a lot.

Comment: lasts for 24 hours when the blog post is new